# How to sub set a vector in an for loop?

Tags: r

I am struggling to subset a vector from a larger vector.

Below is a sample of my data set that I import into r from a CSV file.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGru7.png

I added the 1's at the top so that the csv could be read by R with the correct columns.

I am only interested in the 3rd column (SiO2 (A)) and rows numbered 1-49 in each data entry. The sample data has two data entry's, but other CSV files can have more.

Here is the code that I am running.

```
#Read CSV file into R and call it "dini1"

dini1<-read.csv("aft1-2.csv")

#Isolate column of interests and set as numeric 

nini1<-as.numeric(dini1$X1.2)

#Find the locations of "na" so I know where to start and end my data sub set

loc_nas<-which(is.na(nini1))

#Find the difference between the locations of the "na" using the diff() function, since I know my data set of interest is 49 points

diff_loc<-diff(loc_nas)

#Find my start vector of all the locations that have a difference of more than 8

start<- which(diff_loc > 8 )

#Now I can sub set my 49 points using  brackets [] 

n = 1 #for my first data set and 2 for my second data set

fianl_data<-nini1[c((loc_nas[start[n]]+2(loc_nas[start[n]]+diff_loc[start[n+1]])-1)]
```

What I would like to do is execute the above function in a for loop so that the number of data sets in my vector can change but the code would automatically recognize it. I thought something like a for loop would work but I get an error. Below is the for loop I tried. Please help!

```
library(magicfor)
magic_for(print, silent = TRUE)

#set my criteria using the length of my "start" vector 

vlength <-length(start)-1

#Execute the loop with the magic result so that the data sets are stored

a<-0
for (i in 0:vlength){
  
  a<-i+1
  fdata<-nini1[c((loc_nas[start[a]]+2):(loc_nas[start[a]]+diff_loc[start[a+1]])-1)]
  print(a)
  print(fdata)
}

magic_result_as_dataframe()
```

Comment: selcome to SO! i can see a few problems. 1) you don't need a<-0. just set `for (i in 1:vlength){...` then you can replace the a. one step less to do. 2) you can give the for loop a name (`blah<-for()...`) which allows you to save the results without calling for `magic_result_as_dataframe()` .

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added your suggestions and I still get the following error.  Error in (loc_nas[start[a]] + 2):(loc_nas[start[a]] + diff_loc[start[a +  : 
  NA/NaN argument

Comment: that would be because you didn't change the a to i, i assume